# How to create a unit test for code that calls scrollIntoView on an HTML element

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a method in an Angular component that scrolls a list of elements (called "cards") by selecting one of those cards given some criteria and then calling the scrollIntoView() method.  I've tried a variety of things to try and cover this method with a unit test (jasmine framework) but just can't seem to figure out how to make it work.  Any input would be appreciated!

Here's the method:

```
 scrollToCard() {
    const scrollSlotToMatch = '10:00 - 11:00';

    // Query the DOM to locate schedule card view elements that we want to choose from to scroll into view
    const matches = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('test-card'));

    // Iterate through the card elements to find the appropriate one that matches the target scroll time
    let selectedCard: HTMLElement | undefined;
    for (let i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
      const card = matches[i] as HTMLElement;
      const cardInnerText = card.innerText.split('\n');

      if (cardInnerText[0] === scrollSlotToMatch) {
        selectedCard = card;
        break;
      }
    }

    // If we successfully located a card element, scroll it into view
    if (selectedCard !== undefined) {
      selectedCard.scrollIntoView();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test, you could get a list of `test-card` native elements and, iterating over that list, create a spy for each element's `scrollIntoView` method. With those spies collected into an array, you could then verify that the correct spy was called based on its array index, which would correspond to the element's index.

So, assuming the template for the component you're testing includes `test-card`s like this:

```html
<test-card content="8:00 - 9:00"></test-card>
<test-card content="9:00 - 10:00"></test-card>
<test-card content="10:00 - 11:00"></test-card>
<test-card content="11:00 - 12:00"></test-card>
```

your test would look something like this:

```
it('scrolls the target element into view', () => {
  const targetText = '10:00 - 11:00';
  const expectedCardIndex = 2;

  const cardDebugEls = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('test-card'));
  const scrollSpies = cardDebugEls.map((cardDebugEl: DebugElement) => {
    return spyOn(cardDebugEl.nativeElement, 'scrollIntoView').and.stub();
  });

  component.scrollToCard(targetText);

  scrollSpies.forEach((spy: jasmine.Spy, index) => {
    const expectedCallCount = index === expectedCardIndex ? 1 : 0;
    expect(spy.calls.count()).toBe(expectedCallCount);
  });
});
```

[Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-jasmine-vbnttz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts) showing this approach.